# Get keys of dictionary and subdictionary. The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#

I have the following dictionary:

```
Dictionary<String, Dictionary<Frame, List<Node>>> items;
```

I need to get a tuple with the Keys of the first and second dicionary:

```
List<(String Key, List<Frame> FrameKeys)>
```

So I tried:

```
var keys = items.Select(x => new (x.Key, x.Value.Keys)).ToList();
```

But I get the error:

```
The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, int, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Get rid of the the `new`, it's not required when making tuples in new notation (as opposed to e.g. `ValueTuple`): `items.Select(x => (x.Key, x.Value.Keys)).ToList()`  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples - The error is saying it can't determine what type the `new` cannot be inferred, refers to a new language feature of C# 9 where you can omit the type if the target type is already known. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator#constructor-invocation

Comment: Also, why are you calling `ToList()`? Often it's not needed, and it can save you a **LOT** of overhead and memory if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bad error message, remove the new

```
var keys2 = items.Select(x => (x.Key, x.Value.Keys));
```